# Chrome Caching CORS, denying requests without consulting backend

Tags: cors

I have a react app `https://frontend-dev-domain.com` calling a python (flask) backend `https://backend-dev-domain.com`. Initially I had forgotten to set CORS headers on the backend so the frontend could not reach the backend http status `401`.

I subsequently have set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the backend but the frontend is still unable to call the backend. Chrome seems to be caching the fact that the request was denied and refuses now to contact the backend.

Chrome's DEV tools show the request...
[image]

...but it's not arriving at the backend (as I can see from the python console log).

"Disable cache" is checked in Chrome Dev tools. When I open the backend URL and check the header it definitely set:

[image]

Console error is:

> Access to fetch at 'https://5000-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io/api/shopping-list' from origin 'https://5173-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

However the header IS present.

Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://5173-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io` to the explicit origin (instead of `*`) does not help, neither does specifying `Vary: Origin`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is the request being „blocked“?

Comment: What does the error message from your browser's Console tab say?

Comment: It says it's blocked due to CORS `Access to fetch at 'https://5000-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io/api/shopping-list' from origin 'https://5173-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` But it's "lying" - the header is most definitely present.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by adding `credentials: "include"` to the fetch request as well as the following CORS headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://5173-cawoodm-pyreact-oft7hvkp559.ws-eu105.gitpod.io
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

I do think it's a bug in Chrome which reports the header is not present.

The final explanation for the issue appears to be that my requests, unbeknownst to me, required credentials. As soon as credentials are required you can't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.